# What's the simplest way to customize `git log`, truncating the author email at the `@`?

Tags: regex, git, bash, awk, sed

I wanted to have a git log format, which is essentially the `oneline` pretty format, but including the author email.

Since I'm trying to make the format as compact as possible, in addition to using the short hash, I'd like to use the author email truncated at the `@`.

Right now, my format is:

```
%h | %<(10,trunc)%ae | %s
```

which yields an output similar to:

```
2821c992ff | dev12@yi.. | a commit
e45d9c934b | dev13abc.. | another commit
```

This is acceptable, since the author emails are 10 chars max before the `@`, but the email end format is somewhat messy.

I'm looking for the simplest way to truncate at the `@`, yielding an output like:

```
2821c992ff | dev12    | a commit
e45d9c934b | dev13abc | another commit
```

The crucial concept is to truncate at the `@`.

As refence, I'm using the latest git (2.11.x).

Comment: With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), forget `awk`/`sed`/`perl` and use the pretty format `%al` placeholder: `git log --pretty=format:"Author email %ae has local-part %al`. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58846683/6309).

Answer (score 4):

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), the custom format for "`git log --format=<format>`" learned the `l/L` placeholder that is similar to `e/E` that fills in the e-mail address, **but only the local part on the left side of '`@`'**.

See [commit d8b8217](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8b8217c8a16944dc61a1553464efabc450a6680) (29 Oct 2019), and [commit 45e206f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45e206f0d845cfc85c39c98d0090104e72176d71), [commit 2ae4944](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2ae4944aac4afd3b114729ef4b5b833c7d8fd832) (24 Oct 2019) by [Prarit Bhargava (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c22f63c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c22f63c40f0a576f3938dfd26c976ec052aa7fe2), 10 Nov 2019)</sup>

> ### [`pretty`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8b8217c8a16944dc61a1553464efabc450a6680): add "`%aL`" etc. to show local-part of email addresses
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Prarit Bhargava</sup>

> In many projects the number of contributors is low enough that users know each other and the full email address doesn't need to be displayed.
> **Displaying only the author's username saves a lot of columns on the screen**.

> Existing '`e/E`' (as in "`%ae`" and "`%aE`") placeholders would show the author's address as "`prarit@redhat.com`", which would waste columns to show the same domain-part for all contributors when used in a project internal to redhat.

> Introduce '`l/L`' placeholders that strip '`@`' and domain part from the e-mail address.

---

Note, as noted in Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), `%cl`/`%cL` stand for committer, not author.

See [commit 087bf54](https://github.com/git/git/commit/087bf5409c4f0136d7443e4cda0845e1a95ec16d) (23 Jun 2020) by [Miroslav Koškár (`mkoskar`)](https://github.com/mkoskar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5c61d10](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c61d10b16ad949af9adf824ae3fd4f62a5142e7), 06 Jul 2020)</sup>

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/087bf5409c4f0136d7443e4cda0845e1a95ec16d): fix author vs. committer copy/paste error
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Miroslav Koškár</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `GNU Awk gensub()` function to remove everything after the `@` part from column 2,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$2=gensub(/@.*$/," ","g",$2);}1' file
2821c992ff | dev12.. | a commit
e45d9c934b | dev13abc.. | another commit
```

Or in a pipe-line(`|`) do,

```
.. | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$2=gensub(/@.*$/,".. ","g",$2);}1'
```

(or) as you indicated in the comments below, if you do not want the `..` part, remove it from the substitution part in `gensub()` as

```
.. | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$2=gensub(/@.*$/," ","g",$2);}1'
```

Comment: if the email is not truncated I don't see the use of `..`.   Also, `sub(/@.*/,"",$2)` is enough

Comment: @karakfa: Thanks for the suggestion in `sub()`, had the same question, if `..` actually constituted a part of column value or just representing etc. Need input from OP for that. For now just suggested the op for the given input

Comment: The `..` is not required - it is optional, in the case that there was a way in git itself of performing the replacement (which, based on your answer, there isn't). Since the answer uses a tool external to git, then there is no need to include `..`.

Comment: @Marcus: did it solve the problem except the `..` part? My update fixed it

Comment: Yes, it did solve. A few notes: in the pipe version, `file` must not be used; the suggest `sub` version should probably be used, as it's simpler (although doesn't yield the expected outcome when used as `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$2=sub(/@.*$/,"",$2);}1'`); finally, regardless of gensub/sub, the output is misaligned.

Comment: @Marcus: I am sure you will beleive it being a 'typo' when I say it :)

Comment: @Marcus: When you say it being `misaligned`, if you can let know how it should be, I can correct it, or if things look fine, don't forget to accept/upvote on the answer.

Comment: Misalignment sample: ```c6cbaa65ff | developer1 | A commit!
61c5aa1cff | dev2 | Another commit!``` (multi-line).

Comment: @Marcus: Comments section doesn't allow proper formatting of text, update in the question so that I can clearly understand the difference.!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135758/discussion-between-marcus-and-inian).

Answer (score 1):

With the assumption that each author email prefix (the part before the `@`) is max 10 characters long, the following will accomplish the the job:

```
git log --pretty='%h | %<(11,trunc)%ae | %s' | perl -pe 's/(@\S+)/" " x length($1)/e'
```

It's not possible (or easy) to use a straight regex replacement, because a simple `/@\S+//` type of replacement would cause the second column entries to be of variable length, misaligning the "table".

The perl command above solves the alignment problem by using a perl regex feature - execution of code inside the regex expression (`s///e`).

The regex also relies on the fact that the hash won't have any `@` symbols, therefore the one match it will replace will always be the second column; this is also the reason why truncation happens at 11 - the `@` always needs to be printed in the second column.